# Suppress 0-values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the created the following bar plot with ggplot:

```
library(tidyverse)
temp<-tribble(
 ~kt, ~yes, ~'no', ~'NA',
 "Berne", 47,33, 0,
 "Basel", 60,45,0,
 "Geneva", 64,61,0,
 "Zurich", 19,107,3
)

temp2 <- gather(temp, ' ', val, -kt)
ggplot(temp2, aes(fct_rev(kt), val, fill = ` `)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'fill', color='black') +
  geom_text(aes(label = val), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size=3) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+theme_bw()+
  labs(x='Canton', y='Percentage')+coord_flip()+     scale_fill_grey(start = 0.9, end = .5)+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Label", reverse=T))
```

However, those 0-values on the right side look very disturbing. Is there a way to suppress them in ggplot?

Comment: Maybe you can filter dataframe before plotting. Such as: `temp2 %>% filter(val !=0) %>% ggplot(aes(fct...` and the rest of your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter them with:

`` temp2 <- gather(temp, ' ', val, -kt)
filter(temp2, val>0) %>% 
ggplot(aes(fct_rev(kt), val, fill = ` `)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'fill', color='black') +
  geom_text(aes(label = val), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size=3) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())+theme_bw()+
  labs(x='Canton', y='Percentage')+coord_flip()+     scale_fill_grey(start = 0.9, end = .5)+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Label", reverse=T)) ``

[image]

Is that what you were looking for?